# Creating an ics file from data on a PDF file

Tags: pdf, icalendar

I'm looking for a way to convert a PDF document into multiple ics files that staff can use to add their fortnight roster to their smart phone calendars or outlook calendar on their desktops. The information required to create the multiple files would be pulled from the PDF by searching for selected initials from each column then referencing data from the same row as the initials. Is their a particular order I need the data to appear in the ics file to allow it to import to a smartphone calendar??

Answer (score 0):

You can search for pdf APIs for more details in handling a pdf using programmatically.

and here are some online converters that could help. They convert a pdf into word

http://www.pdftoword.com/success.aspx

http://www.pdfescape.com/account/?expired

However, reconstructing structured data from PDF is not trivial because a program has to deduct the semantics in the layout. So most programs can only restore scattered data from a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with PERL and windows Adobe PDF viewer to highlight all the text in the PDF and cut and paste to a text file.  As the previous answer said, you have to write PERL (or any other text processing language) to pick out the format of the PDF you have.  Then you can print it with PERL to csv or to ical or whatever format you want.  I've shared my code on github.com.  I'm not sure if you know GIT, but send me a private message if you want me to send the PERL code outside of GIT.

The PDF's I've converted are here:

http://recplexonline.com/sports/hockey/old-geezers-hockey-35

The Git hub of my PERL code and the input files I used are here:

https://github.com/jdeltoft/PdfParse

It's pretty ugly perl, sorry for that.  But it works.  I'll try to clean it up soon.